# What do we call ions without basic and acidic properties

Tags: acid-base, aqueous-solution, solutions, ions

According to Brønsted theory,

1. Acids are substances (molecules and ions) donating $\ce{H+}$
2. Bases are substances (molecules and ions) receiving $\ce{H+}$

I've been trying to find a complete Brønsted-Lowry's Base and Acid charts. But I cannot find the chart mention "substances without basic or acidic properties" such as $\ce{CO}$, $\ce{Na+}$, $\ce{K+}$, $\ce{Cl-}$, etc..

Could anyone help me with what I should call these substances? And a keyword for a Brønsted-Lowry chart that also includes the substances with no basic and acid properties? All my learning is in my non-native language English. Right now my current English lecture composed by the University doesn't mention the category for the matter I've been looking for.

Comment: CO is a neutral compound.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the word you are looking for is a pH-neutral compound, or simply a neutral compound.

Answer (score 1):

I think your best bet would be neutral salts. This term describes compounds such as $\ce{NaCl, KNO3, CaBr2, CsClO4}$. This [page](http://www.science.uwaterloo.ca/~cchieh/cact/c123/salts.html) from the University of Waterloo gives a brief table of ions that when paired produce a neutral salt.